# Confusion about notation in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry book

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This comes from page 125 in the chapter on isometric immersions.

Setup:

$f:M \rightarrow \bar{M}$ is an immersion. For each $p \in M$ there exists a neibhborhood $U \subset M$ of $p$ such that $f(U) \subset \bar{M}$ is a submanifold of $\bar{M}$.

He says to simplify the notation we will identify $U$ with $f(U)$ and each $v \in T_q M$, $q \in U$ with $df_q v \in T_{f(q)}\bar{M}$.

> Here is where I get confused:

He says, for each $p \in M$, the inner product on $T_p \bar{M}$ splits $T_p\bar{M}$ into the direct sum $T_p\bar{M}=T_pM \oplus (T_pM)^{\perp}$.

Further, if $v \in T_p \bar{M}$, $p \in M$, we can write $v=v^{T}+v^{N}$ where $v^T \in T_p M$ and $v^N \in (T_p M)^\perp$. He says such a splitting is clearly differentiable, in the sense that the mappings $(p,v) \mapsto (p,v^T)$ and $(p,v)\mapsto (p,v^N)$ of $T\bar{M}$ into $T\bar{M}$ are clearly differentiable.

> My issue with this:
>
> 1. I think every instance of $T_p \bar{M}$ should be replaced by $T_{f(p)}\bar{M}$,(i.e. we identify $T_p M$ with $df_p(T_p M) \subset T_f(p)\bar{M})$, unless
> 2. if $p \in U$ then we could make the identifications that he stated which would make more sense, however, he says this for $p \in M$, not just $p \in U$, and
> 3. He made the "mistake" of using $p$ several times which makes me believe that he meant to.
>
> So what is going on here? Is he just being incredibly sloppy or am I missing something here?

Comment: Manfredo tries to avoid bundles like the plague, so he is not clear here that he means to split the pull-back bundle of the tangent bundle of $\overline{M}$. The point is: we don't need $f$ to be injective. So for two different $p_1,p_2$ such that $f(p_1)=f(p_2)$, the induced spliting of $T_{f(p)}\overline{M}$ could be different. Hence, he sticks with $p$, puts it under the rug and hopes that it is not relevant for the computations that follow (and really, if you stop thinking about it and only think about it later, you may come to the conclusion that this may be a good pedagogic choice).